# Foundatoin reveal: foundation.core.js:190 TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, zurb-foundation

I have installed foundation 6 and all appeared to be working ok so far. Now I wanted to add a reveal modal. jQuery v2.2.4 is added and the loaded the necessary libraries as below from FOUNDATION_VERSION = '6.2.1';:

```
<script src="/assets/js/foundation.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/foundation.util.mediaQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/foundation.reveal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
</body>
```

Then added the example modal from the foundation website:

```
<p><a data-open="exampleModal1">Click me for a modal</a></p>

<div class="reveal" id="exampleModal1" data-reveal>
    <h1>Awesome. I Have It.</h1>
    <p class="lead">Your couch. It is mine.</p>
    <p>I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!</p>
    <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

On loading the page I see a console log error:

foundation.core.js:190 TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined

I tried to load the tabs library and again copy the example html but the same issue occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some digging around it seems that reveal also has further dependencies:

```
<script src="/assets/js/foundation.util.keyboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/foundation.util.box.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/foundation.util.triggers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

After including these additional libraries the issue was resolved.

Comment: This worked, is there a page which lists dependencies of all the foundation plugins?

Comment: Each js plugin file lists it's dependencies as @require comments, for example: https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop/js/foundation.responsiveMenu.js

Comment: it seems foundation.util.keyboard.js is also required for offcanvas, although not listed as a @require or in the docs

Answer (score 0):

Here are my exact includes for reveal modals

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.3/css/foundation.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.3/css/foundation-float.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.3/js/plugins/foundation.core.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.3/js/foundation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.3/js/plugins/foundation.reveal.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.3/js/plugins/foundation.util.keyboard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.3/js/plugins/foundation.util.triggers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.3/js/plugins/foundation.util.mediaQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.3/js/plugins/foundation.util.motion.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like jfxninja said, dependencies are required, but you need to dig through the JS files to find each `@requires`. So here's a list of all of them.

*(Sorry to necro, this is the first result for this issue)*

```
foundation.abide:
    → NA (no dependancies)

foundation.accordion:
    → foundation.util.keyboard

foundation.accordionMenu:
    → foundation.util.keyboard
    → foundation.util.nest

foundation.drilldown:
    → foundation.util.keyboard
    → foundation.util.nest
    → foundation.util.box

foundation.dropdown:
    → foundation.util.keyboard
    → foundation.util.box
    → foundation.util.triggers

foundation.dropdownMenu:
    → foundation.util.keyboard
    → foundation.util.box
    → foundation.util.nest

foundation.equalizer:
    → foundation.util.mediaQuery
    → foundation.util.imageLoader // if equalizer contains images

foundation.interchange:
    → foundation.util.mediaQuery

foundation.magellan:
    → foundation.smoothScroll

foundation.offcanvas:
    → foundation.util.keyboard
    → foundation.util.mediaQuery
    → foundation.util.triggers

foundation.orbit:
    → foundation.util.keyboard
    → foundation.util.motion
    → foundation.util.timer
    → foundation.util.imageLoader
    → foundation.util.touch

foundation.responsiveAccordionTabs:
    → foundation.util.motion
    → foundation.accordion
    → foundation.tabs

foundation.responsiveMenu:
    → foundation.util.triggers
    → foundation.util.mediaQuery

foundation.responsiveToggle:
    → foundation.util.mediaQuery
    → foundation.util.motion

foundation.reveal:
    → foundation.util.keyboard
    → foundation.util.triggers
    → foundation.util.mediaQuery
    → foundation.util.motion // if using animation
    → foundation.util.touch

foundation.slider:
    → foundation.util.motion
    → foundation.util.triggers
    → foundation.util.keyboard
    → foundation.util.touch

foundation.smoothScroll:
    → NA (no dependancies)

foundation.sticky:
    → foundation.util.triggers
    → foundation.util.mediaQuery

foundation.tabs:
    → foundation.util.keyboard
    → foundation.util.imageLoader // if tabs contain images

foundation.toggler:
    → foundation.util.motion
    → foundation.util.triggers

foundation.tooltip:
    → foundation.util.box
    → foundation.util.mediaQuery
    → foundation.util.triggers
```